# List items not staying in place using react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using react-beautiful-dnd and copied the code from the tutorial to build a draggable list. It worked and looked like this:

[image]

And here's the code that built this: https://github.com/DDavis1025/react-beautiful-dnd

However now I'm trying to implement my own list which is a playlist that uses the input to add songs from the user's computer to the list:

[image]

It's partially working but I'm not able to drag the list item in place (It always goes back to the same order).
Here is the code that I changed:

**column-test.jsx**

```
export default class ColumnTest extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

    this.inputRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      files: [],
      audio: '',
    };

  }



handleClick = event => {

  // Helper code to read file and return promise
  const readFile = (file) => {

    const fileList = [];

    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    // create the promise and return it
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      // if file reader has an error, report it
      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject({ error })
      }

      // if success, resolve the promise
      fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        resolve({
          name: file.name,
          link: e.target.result
        })
      }

      // start reading the file
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    })
  }


  // create all the file reader promises
  // create an array from the files list and use map to generate
  // an array of promises
  const allReaders = Array.from(event.target.files).map(readFile)

  // Now handle the array of promises we just created
  Promise.all(allReaders)
    .then(fileList => {
      console.log(fileList)
      // set the state that we have all the files
      this.setState({ files: fileList });
    })
    .catch(error => { 
       console.error(error)
    });


}





  render() {
      return (
      <div className="downloadMusic">
      <div className="input">
        <input
          onChange={this.handleClick}
          id="upload-file"
          className="inputName"
          type="file"
          multiple
          ref={this.inputRef}
        />
        </div>
        <div className="audio-player">

       <audio
       controls
       autoPlay
       src={this.state.audio}
        />
         </div>



        <Container>
           <Title>{this.props.column.title}</Title>
           <Droppable droppableId={this.props.column.id}>
            {provided => (
             <TaskList
               ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
              {this.state.files.map((file, index) => (
               <TaskTest key={file.link} file={file} index={index} />
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}

             </TaskList>

             )}
            </Droppable>
        </Container>

        </div>
        );
  }
}
```

(This is where I add my input and fileReader to add files to my files array and iterate through those files using the .map() function in return() in render{})

**task-test.jsx**

```
export default class TaskTest extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <Draggable draggableId={this.props.file.link} index={this.props.index}>
           {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <Container
              {...provided.draggableProps}
              {...provided.dragHandleProps}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
            >
            {this.props.file.name}
            </Container>
           )}
          </Draggable>
          );
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-beautiful-dnd requires you to manage your own list, which means reordering the array after an item has been "dropped". Do accomplish this, there are a few things you need to add:

**A function to handle the "drop"**

```
  onDragEnd(result) {
    // dropped outside the list
    if (!result.destination) {
      return;
    }

    const files = reorder(
      this.state.files,
      result.source.index,
      result.destination.index
    );

    this.setState({
      files
    });
  }
```

**Bind onDragEnd in your constructor**

```
this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this);
```

**A function to reorder the array**

```
const reorder = (list, startIndex, endIndex) => {
  const result = Array.from(list);
  const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
  result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);

  return result;
};
```

**A DragDropContext around your droppable**

```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}> 
    <Droppable droppableId={this.props.column.id}>
    ...
```

You can view an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/k260nyxq9v

Comment: Ok I like this. How would I add my files array to the code in code sandbox?

Comment: I think I got it to work using your code. Thank you sir.